# Is there a way to remove the credentials page provided by spring Security completely and use Custom Authentication Provider for a CSRF implementation?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement a CSRF token implementation based on Spring Security and Angular 4. The initial authentication to my application is using the organization's SSO page. Post which we are redirected to the application home page. Below is my implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter using 2 layers of filters, 1 to check and add CSRF token other is for apps internal authentication purposes to provide method level security using @Secured.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
          
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProviderService authenticationProviderService;

    public static final String CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN";

    private static final String[] CSRF_IGNORE = { ""};

    private static final String CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    @Component
    @Order(1)
    public class CustomCsrfFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

            if (csrf != null) {

                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
                String token = csrf.getToken();

                if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    cookie.setHttpOnly(false);
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public FilterRegistrationBean createFilterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new OncePerRequestFilter() {

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

                try {
                        // App method specific authentication code
                        return;
                    }

                } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Authentication error", e);
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                    response.sendRedirect("/error/unauthorized.html");
                    return;
                }

            }

     
            @Override
            protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
                String uri = request.getRequestURI();
                return uri.startsWith("/resources/") || uri.startsWith("/static/") || uri.startsWith("/css/")
                        || uri.startsWith("/images/") || uri.startsWith("/js/") || uri.startsWith("/api/tct/")
                        || uri.startsWith("/api/unit/unitConversion");
            }
        });

        return registration;
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic()
        .and().csrf() // csrf config starts here
                .ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE) // URI where CSRF check will not be applied
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()) // defines a repository where tokens are stored
                .and().addFilterAfter(new CustomCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                ; // Csrf filter in
        // which we will add
        // the cookie

    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {

        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");

        return tokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderService);
    }

}
```

here is my code in Angular for embedding CSRF token:

app module's providers

```
{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }

custom interceptor to append cookies:

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }
  //function which will be called for all http calls
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let requestToForward = request;
    let token = getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
    if (token != null) {
      requestToForward = request.clone(
        { setHeaders: { 'XSRF-TOKEN': token } });
    }

    return next.handle(requestToForward);
  }
}

function getCookie(name: String) {
  const splitCookie = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitCookie.length; i++) {

    const splitValue = splitCookie[i].split('=');
    if (splitValue[0] === name) {
      return splitValue[1];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

So I am getting this popup on few POST requests for username and password. Since I have implemented a custom authentication I don't rely on the input provided on this default form for my validation and it's basically just needs to press sign In when it comes up without providing any details. I would want to remove this pop-up as it really doesn't have any purpose to be there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: implementing custom security is bad practice.

Comment: @Thomas  I don't need the entire authentication/authorisation piece but I do need just the CSRF implementation.I have tried disabling the http Basic via appllication.yml by security.basic.enabled:false but unable to achieve that too.

Comment: If you are unable to disable it you are doing it wrong. Check the official documentation. Its all in there.

Comment: @Thomas I believe its more related to the custom implementation related to the version of spring security that i’m using.The project is based on Spring Boot 1.7 and hence an upgrade to one of the newer versions will cause many of the functionalities to break.It would be really helpful if you could share some documentation links for the same version .

Comment: I dont have any documentation links ro something that is that old. Good luck